# Sorting columns in HTML table using Rails or Bootstrap?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, bootstrap-4, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm looking for the best way to implement click (arrow icons) sort per column in an HTML table (not the database table). Is this best done with the boostrap-sortable plugin or best to try and implement an action in Rails to sort (controller method). It currently loads A-Z by name, as implemented by the query.

I have tried referring to: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/tables/sort/ but received console errors that DataTables(); could not be found.

```
@users = User.all
```

```
  <thead>
    <th></th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Phone</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @users.each do |user|  %>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><%= user.full_name %></td>
        <td><%= user.state %></td>
        <td><%= number_to_phone(user.phone_number, area_code: true) %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript console: "DataTable();" cannot be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO I think is better to implement the sort option in the backend, because your list could have 10000 records and you are showing for example 10 per page. If you are delegating the process in the client-side I think this is not a good strategy.

Maybe you can implement a scope in order to resolve the problem. The index action of the controller must have params in the query string to apply for the order.

example:

myurl?order=asc&by=name

Then in the index action you